# How to handle pronouns with verbs that use "à" ?

Tags: grammaire

For example, take the verb *résister à*. I could say:

> Il résiste aux ennemies.

But if I was going to use an object pronoun instead, what does this become? I know that *y* goes with *à* verbs in this way, but if I wanted to say "he is resisting *me*", I can't convey that with *Il y résiste.* Is *il me résiste* wrong? Or is it *il résiste à moi*?

Comment: Really good answer there, very helpful, thanks.